# rails active record male and female error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, rails-i18n

sorry for my english.

There is a way to translate correctly male and female model names for spanish languages, for example:

```
es:
  test: 
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one: Ocurrió un error mientras se guardaba esta %{model}. Por favor corrija los datos.
```

Take a look to "**esta**" word, that indicates a female model, for male models the word should be "**este**".

Comment: Are you trying to come up with an error logic only from es.yml? I.e. are you avoiding implementing this error check in the controller/model? 
Your question and example are very hard to understand. Could you try to improve it? Please give a **clear** question and indicate if there is something specific you want to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at this gem: `https://github.com/siefca/i18n-inflector`.  It might give you what you need.

Comment: Does the model implement a method or have an attribute that defines if it’s male or female?